# Download button in react

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, cloudinary

I want to make a download button. So, users can download zip files. I stored my files in Cloudinary. I am using **react**.
I tried a couple of ways to implement that but I am not able to that. When I click on the button it just extends the route like this.

http://localhost:3000/books/dsdfdsdsds to http://localhost:3000/books/dsdfdsdsds/https://MY_Cloudinary_Link

```
<button href="MY_Cloudinary_Link" target="_self" download className="bg-secondary text-white font-bold py-3 px-5 rounded text-2xl focus:outline-none mt-3"><i className="animate-bounce fas fa-arrow-down mr-2"></i>Download</button>
```

I tried a link tag as well, it also didn't work form me.
Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the target attribute and use the `attachment` flag in Cloudinary (`fl_attachment`) as part of your delivery URL.

For example -

```
<a href="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/fl_attachment/sample.jpg">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for images but when I try this for zip files it didn't work. It shows me this error (This res.cloudinary.com page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address):

Comment: And I want to know we need to manually add this flag to every url or there is some way of doing this.

Comment: Firstly, when accessing delivery URLs for ZIP file these will download automatically without needing this flag. Regarding the ZIP file URLs not working - most likely this is due to a new policy on Cloudinary that blocks PDF/Archive files on delivery for Free accounts registered after April 2020. If your account matches that description then you would need to raise a ticket with Cloudinary to remove the restriction. You can raise a ticket using - https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new.

Comment: In terms of adding the flag - if you are using one of Cloudinary's SDKs, such as the React one (https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_integration) then those provide helper functions (or components in React case) that will generate URLs for you when you pass parameters to them. For example, you can generate the above sample.jpg URL by using the React SDK like so -

```
<Image publicId="sample.jpg" >
  <Transformation flags="attachment" />
</Image>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I recently created my account.

Comment: Till now, I just copy the cloudinary url from the dashboard and paste it wherever I want. Is there any better of doing this so that I can easily add flag to the url. If i just copy paste the url so I need to manually add the flag.

Comment: I am not using any sdk. I just upload the file directly from the dashboard and copy the link.

Comment: I would recommend you to use the relevant SDK and not to deliver assets (images/videos specifically) by just using the URL from the Dashboard. That delivers the original resources which is not optimized and often large in size. That will consume a lot of your Bandwidth. Using the SDK allows you to easily build URLs with Transformations - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_optimization which will reduce the filesize of assets you deliver.

Comment: Thanks Aleksandar. you are really very helpful

Comment: Hey Aleksandar, Is it Ok to share public url of the assets?

Comment: Certainly, if you want the URLs to be publicly accessible you can share them. If you want to upload resources and for them not to be public then you can upload resources as "type: private" (which prevents access to the original without a signed URL) and combine it with Strict Transformations (for images/videos) such that it prevents Transformations to be created on your account without a signature. You can also use produce a time-limited URL that can be used to download "private" assets if needed.
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/control_access_to_media#private_media_assets

Comment: Where will the public id of the images be found?

Comment: The public_id is can be automatically generated by Cloudinary (i.e. random, or using the filename + a unique suffix), or be configured to use the filename as the public_id, or you can supply the public_id yourself in an upload call. It would depend on how you would like the public_id to be. The public_id is returned in API resopnses and is what is displayed as the name (identifier) in the Media Library.

Answer (score 0):

Button doesn't have a href attribute. You should provide (a) tag and inside that you can add href attribute with relative or absolute path.
Please check this out. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp